# Debug Blazor webasm in visual studio code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, web-applications, blazor

I have followed Microsoft's [Blazor Tutorial - Build your first Blazor app](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/next), and I am now trying to debug it in visual studio code.

when i run the debugger, it 'starts' the webapp, and opens edge... but it doesn't select the page, and visual studio code comes with an error message after a few seconds: [image: error message]

when I run without  the debugger, i get the following error message: [image]

in both cases, the webapp is started, and I can visit the app with no problems, just vscode has no connection and cannot debug, or select the correct page...

launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "name": "Launch and Debug Blazor WebAssembly Application",
            "request": "launch",
            "browser": "edge",
            "url": "https://localhost:5001",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

any idea what the problem can be

Comment: I have now learned that the original project was a 'Blazor server' project, and not 'Blazor webassembly'... But creating the correct project... "dotnet new blazorwasm..." and configuring the debugger paying close attention to the visual studio code guide from Microsoft... brings me at exacly the same error on my other machine :/